# How to import multiple different delimited files in sas?

Tags: file, import, sas

I have a folder with multiple files. Each in different category (say for example: 5 files are tab delimited, 5 are csv files, 5 are pipe delimited and so on). How can I import them using SAS? (I don't want to import them separately.)

Comment: Are the files the same structure otherwise, ie same variables?

Comment: You don't mention how you will import details are important.  If you use a data step program you can read them all as one stream.  Review the INFILE statement documentation and you will see that DLM= can specify a variable that contains the delimiter.

Comment: They all have same variables. I have to read them and append them as one single file. I want to know whether a single approach for reading multiple files exist?

Comment: Many approaches exist.  Have you looked?  There are plenty of questions about this kind of thing, plus papers google-able.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.  If you can make logic to determine the delimiter from looking at the line then it should be easy.  Let's make some example files.

```
%let path=%sysfunc(pathname(work));
data _null_;
  set sashelp.class ;
  if _n_ < 7 then file "&path/1_csv.txt" dsd dlm=',';
  else if _n_ < 13 then file "&path/2_tab.txt" dsd dlm='09'x;
  else file "&path/3_pipe.txt" dsd dlm='|' ;
  put (_all_) (+0);
run;
```

Now let's try to read them. First read in the line and then set the DLM variable based on what you see. Then read the data.

```
data want ;
   if 0 then set sashelp.class ;
   length dlm $1.;
   infile "&path/*.txt" dsd dlm=dlm truncover;
   input @;
   if indexc(_infile_,'09'x) then dlm='09'x;
   else if indexc(_infile_,'|') then dlm='|';
   else if indexc(_infile_,',') then dlm=',';
   input name -- weight;
run;
```

Now let's compare the results with the original data.  Note: That depending on your operating system the files might not be read in the same order as they were generated, so you might need to sort before trying to compare.

```
proc compare data=want compare=sashelp.class; run;
```